# ¿Como hacer un responsive topNav con links a la derecha?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap, navbar

Necesito crear un menú responsivo, el cual debe ser el logotipo al lado derecho y los links al lado izquierdo.

Encontré como hacerlos en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav) y es un ejemplo sencillo pero no encuentro como hacer los links al lado derecho, intente con la propiedad `float:right` de `CSS` pero me invierte el orden de los elementos (en la web no he encontrado como solucionarlo).

**Ejemplo utilizando el tutorial de `w3school`**

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:not(:first-child){
  float:right;
}

.topnav a:first-child{
  float:left;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Logo</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Intente también hacerlo con la [`navbar` de `bootstrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/) y es el mismo caso, todos lo utilizan al lado izquierdo.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta :) es un ejemplo funcional con Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con Bootstrap es bastante sencillo, y si piensas usar un framework lo recomiendo ya que usa Flexbox; si te fijas bien en su estructura, el componente del logo se llama `navbar-brand`, este es el primer elemento del navbar; basta con moverlo despues del panel que contiene los enlaces, de modo que se reordenan para mostrar los enlaces a la izquierda, y el `navbar-brand` a la derecha.

Hay un par de cosas que tomar en cuenta, como remover el `margin-right` que tiene por defecto, esto puedes hacerlo agregando la clase `mr-0` al `navbar-brand` y listo; de igual manera seria bueno eliminar la clase `mr-auto` de `navbar-nav` para evitar un margen no deseado.

El problema en este caso termina siendo que el logo ira al fondo del panel cuando la barra se expanda en movil, puedes desactivar este comportamiento si lo deseas, o bien puedes jugar con las clases `order-*` que Bootstrap ofrece para ordenar los elementos dentro del navbar en la posicion que desees.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-2 order-lg-1" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 order-1 order-lg-2" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Me podrías explicar acerca de la clase order

Comment: 1/2... Te recomendaría primeramente familiarizarte mucho con **Flexbox**; Bootstrap 4 esta hecho completamente en Flexbox y esto hace que puedas manipularlo facilmente, ademas te brindan muchas clases para que puedas hacer cambios rapidos... En este caso, la clase [`order`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order) te permite especificar el orden en que los elementos se muestran dentro de un contenedor flex; de manera que modifiques la posicion en que aparecen los elementos aunque se declaren en un orden distinto en el html

Comment: 2/2... Asi, digamos que primero colocas un `nav` y luego un `section` dentro de un contendor flex... normalmente el `nav` se mostraria primero y luego el `section` porque asi estan puestos en el HTML, pero con `order` puedes hacer que primero se muestre `section` y luego `nav` sin tener que modificar tu HTML

Comment: @FernyCortez si esta respuesta resolvio tu problema recuerda marcarla como correcta :)